# AngularJs filter is not working correctly

Tags: angularjs

Please see the link
http://plnkr.co/edit/Cn0sNDGEkPOzV19ye8NW?p=preview 
I have changed my JSON, then I can't able to filter the data.

```
var result = $filter('filter')(foo.results, {id:2426})[0];
```

Comment: You're trying to filter `foo.results`, which doesn't even exist. The code should be in your question.

Comment: Also it's meant for arrays and the json you posted contains no arrays

Comment: But I want to filter out new JSON. Could you please update filter function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you limit on your JSON data

and you can make sure the data property value is num

maybe you can try this ...

```
var foo = {
    "count": 70,
    "language": "en",
    "0": {
      "id": "2420",
      "name": "Medical Center"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "7840",
      "name": "Conference Room"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2426",
      "name": "Deck 5 Starboard"
    }
  };

  foo.results = [];

  for(var property in foo){
    if(property == parseInt(property, 10).toString()){
      foo.results.push(foo[property]);
    }
  }

  var result = $filter('filter')(foo.results, {id:2426})[0];

  $scope.name = result.name;
```

wish help !!